# Tick checkbox from a WHILE loop

Tags: php, mysql

So I have three tables:

```
docs
  doc_id

cats
  cat_id

doc_cat_join
  id
  doc_id
  cat_id
```

I have created a way to create a doc (much like a post) and categories the docs go into the docs table and the categories go into the cats table. when editing a doc I show the available categories by way of a while loop. this works perfectly well whichever ones I tick it take the doc_id form the url and the cat_id of the checkboxes you tick. What I want to do is when I then go back and edit again it only shows ticks in the checkboxes from the ones I selected before by looking at the join table.

Here is how I currently loop through and show the categories:

```
<?php
function build_cat_checkboxes(){

    global $dbc;
    global $id;

    $q = "SELECT * FROM cats";
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

    $currentDoc = $id;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    $checked = (($row['cat_id'] == $currentDoc) ? 'checked' : '');

    echo '<ul>
          <li><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '"  checked="'.$checked.'"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li>
          </ul>';
    }

}
?>
```

As you can see I have attempted to create a way of checking them but all it is doing it ticking all the boxes because my query is obviously wrong as it isnt checking the join table to see if the doc_id is associated with the cat_id

So...

I put together this query:

```
$q1 = "SELECT * FROM doc_cat_join WHERE doc_id = '$id'";
$r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);
```

and if I do a `print_r` on it, it gives me back the numbers of rows I expect by taking the doc_id form the url and then showing me if there is or isn't any rows in the join table associated with the doc I am editing. I need to find a way to tick the checkboxes but I am really struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a `boolean` in your statement by putting it all inside parenthesis;

Replace:

```
$checked = ($row['cat_id'] == $currentDoc) ? 'checked' : '';
<input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '"  checked="'.$checked.'"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li>
</ul>';
```

With:

```
$checked = (($row['cat_id'] == $currentDoc) ? 'checked="checked"' : '');
<input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '" '.$checked.'"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li>
</ul>';
```

Comment: Hmm so it still ticks all checkboxes even with the suggested change.

Comment: Right if it has checked attribute it will be checked. One second editing.

Comment: Ok so none of the checkboxes are ticked now... (Even though the rows exist in the join table)

Comment: Inside of your while, at the begining, add `var_dump($row['cat_id'], $currentDoc);` and check if you get a match

Comment: I believe the query needs to check the join table right? Maybe im wrong but it must check that table to know which ones should be ticked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82342/discussion-between-phpcoder-and-taxicala).

Comment: If you don't get a match, then thats the reason why none of the checkboxes are getting ticked.